# Reading consecutively from a file

Tags: c++, file-io, filestream

I have a program that reads usernames and passwords from a file. The file is arranged like this:

```
Username
Password
Username
Password
...
```

I cant figure out how to get it to read every other one. Here is what I have.

Header:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

class authentication
{
  private:
         string username;
         string password;

  public:
        void authenticate();
        void change_password();            

};
```

class implementation:

```
#include "authentication.h"

void authentication::authenticate()
{
cout << "Enter username\n";
cin >> username;
cout << "Enter password\n";
cin >> password;

string temp_username, temp_password;

 ifstream myfile ("user_list.txt");

 if(myfile.is_open())
 {
     getline(myfile, temp_username);
 }



}
```

Driver:

```
#include "authentication.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
authentication test1;
test1.authenticate();

system("PAUSE");
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You have to get `username` and `password` from a file.  No need to try to get it from `stdin` (`cin`).

Comment: I didn't understand why you are looking for userinput... do you want to match it against the file?

Comment: All the below answers are fine, _if_ you don't allow spaces in your usernames or passwords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your file uses normal white spaces and not linefeeds to discern records. Therefore I would do something like this:

```
struct UserDetails
{
  std::string username_;
  std::string password_;
};

std::istream& operator >> ( std::istream& is, UserDetails& details )
{
  std::string username, password;
  if( is )
  { 
    if( (is >> username) && (is >> password ) )
    { 
      details.username_ = username;
      details.password_ = password;
    } 
  }
  return is;
}

void test()
{
  std::vector<UserDetails> userDetailSeq;
  while( !file.eof() )
  {
    UserDetails details;
    if( file >> details )
      { userDetailSeq.push_back( details ); }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]){
    ifstream input (argv[1]);
    string username, password;
    vector<std::string> userNames;
    vector<std::string> passWords;

    while(input >> username){
         userNames.push_back(username);
         input >> password;
         passWords.push_back(password);
    }

}
```

I didnt read through all of your code to a T, but based on your question and illustration of what the file looks like, this is how I would go about adding your usernames to one vector and your password to another...the indexes will now align for correlating usernames and password as long as you dont allow whitespace within your username or password

Note: you will give path to file for the ifstream input (argv[1]); to work...to do this in xcode, go to product, scheme, edit scheme, hit the plus sign and type in the path to your file in quotes...

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to extract individual usernames and passwords from the file, try using the `operator >> ()` like this:

```
myfile >> temp_username ;
myfile >> temp_password ;
```